# Calculating the Duplicate Values in an Array

Tags: java

I am suppose to write a program to calculate duplicates in an array. The code works if the are two of the same number. However, there is an error if there are three or more of the same number. How do I go about it?

```
public class Duplicate
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        int[] list = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10};

        int sum = 0;
        for(int count=1; count<list.length; count++)
        {
          if(list[count-1]==list[count])
          {
            sum = list[count-1] + list[count];
            System.out.println("Duplicate found: " + list[count] + " " + "Sum of the duplicate value is " +sum);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is "calculating duplicate numbers"?

Comment: Is the input array always sorted? What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: array will be always sorted??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick for you

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10 };

    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) 
        {
            if (k != j && array[k] == array[j])
            {
                sum = sum + array[k];
                System.out.println("Duplicate found: " + array[k] + " " + "Sum of the duplicate value is " + sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a Java-8-style, functional approach:

```java
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10 };

// Create a Stream<Integer> from your data
IntStream.of(array)
         .boxed()

// Group values into a Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i))

// Filter out those map values that have only 1 element in their group
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)

// Print the sum for the remaining groups
         .forEach(e -> {
             System.out.println(
                 "Duplicates found for : " + e.getKey() +
                 " their sum being : " + e.getValue()
                                          .stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i)));
         });
```

For your input, this yields:

```
Duplicates found for : 8 their sum being : 24
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it works for unordered `int[]` just the same. E.g. for...

```java
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 10, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10 };
```

The output will be...

```
Duplicates found for : 3 their sum being : 6
Duplicates found for : 8 their sum being : 32
Duplicates found for : 10 their sum being : 20
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind to use Javaslang, a collection library for Java 8, here is more a concise solution:

```java
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10 };

// javaslang.collection.List
List.ofAll(array)
        .groupBy(i -> i)
        .entrySet()
        .filter(e -> e.value.length() > 1)
        .forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println(
                    "Duplicates found for : " + e.key +
                    " their sum being : " + e.value.sum());
        });
```

As expected, this yields to:

```
Duplicates found for : 8 their sum being : 24
```

And, likewise to Lukas' answer, for

```java
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 10, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10 };
```

it yields to

```
Duplicates found for : 10 their sum being : 20
Duplicates found for : 8 their sum being : 32
Duplicates found for : 3 their sum being : 6
```

Please note that this code runs with Javaslang 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, which is released soon.